# Largest, smallest, LUB and GLB of the relation $\leq$on $ \left\{\frac{2n + 1}{n + 1} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I have to fin the largest, smallest, lower/least upper bound (LUB) and greatest lower bound (GLB) element of the relation $\leq$ on the following set:

$$S = \left\{\frac{2n + 1}{n + 1} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

I know more or less what is the smallest and the largest element (if any), that is the 2 elements that are part of set that are respectively the smallest and the largest of all the set.

The LUB (*supremum*)  can be part of the set, but not necessarily, the same for the GLB (*infimum*).

What I am not understanding is the part when they ask for this elements ***of the relation $\leq$ on the set S***. What exactly that means?

I am quite stupid at maths (and in general) and I am not exactly understanding the question. I could find the elements they are asking from a certain set, but what does the relation has to do with this? I know I am probably not thinking to some key point, I am sorry.

Comment: Hint: use induction to show that it is an increasing sequence. so the first term will be GLB. LUB is 2.

Comment: You are understanding the problem just fine, but you seem to be missing the concept of *partially ordered set*, which, once understood, should dissipate the confusion regarding 'the relation $\leq$'. So, do you know what a partially ordered set is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S$ is a set of rational numbers.  The relation $\le$ is the usual relation on the rationals.  When you ask about largest and LUB, you need to specify what relation you are using to compare the numbers.  We could choose a different relation on the set $S$ and the answers would change.

Comment: Yes, you are asked for the least element of the set in the usual order.

Comment: I don't know if you think $0 \in \Bbb N$ but let us assume so.  Then $S=\{\frac 11,\frac 32,\frac 53,\frac74,\dots\}$  I can define a relation $\preceq$ by (assuming the fractions are in lowest terms) $\frac ab \preceq \frac cd$ if $b$ is even and $d$ is odd or $\leq$ if $b,d$ have the same parity.  The order then is $\frac 32 \preceq \frac 74 \preceq \frac{11}6 \preceq \dots \preceq \frac 11 \preceq \frac 53 \preceq \frac 95 \preceq \dots$  This would give different answers.

Comment: This is similar to the [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).  You can define many orders on any set.  The hard part is finding one that is easy to describe.  The one I give here is total, like $\le$, in that any two elements can be compared.  Another on $\Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$ is $a \preceq b$ if $a$ divides $b$.  This one is not total.

Answer (score 2):

$GLB = MIN = 3/2, LUB = 2$, there is no $MAX$.

Comment: But the statement said $n \in \mathbb{N}$